# Adding multiple items to QComboBox - QT

Tags: c++, qt

I'm new at programming with QT and I need a combobox with several options.
I'd like to insert all the options with a single line of code, something like this: myCmb->add("one","two","three","four");

This is what i've done so far:

```
QComboBox *myCmb= new QComboBox;
myCmb->addItem("one");
myCmb->addItem("two");
myCmb->addItem("three");
myCmb->addItem("four");
```

It works but I think it's not elegant.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use

```
myCmb->addItems({ "one", "two", "three", "four" });
```

This requires a C++11 compiler for the initializer list constructor of `QStringList` (that is the type of the parameter to `addItems`).

In practical terms, that means adding

```
CONFIG += c++11
```

to the qmake project.

Comment: You can also use `CONFIG += c++11`

Comment: That is probably the better way, now that you mention it, so I edited it in.

Comment: Let's thank the Qt staff for building a `QStringList` that takes an `initializer_list`. Way to go, folks.

Answer (score 7):

Or use

```
myCmb->addItems(QStringList() << "one" << "two" << "three" << "four" );
```